# How to fix auto-indentation of previous line when entering newline?

Tags: indentation

Suppose I have this indentation:

```elixir
with {:ok, _} <-
       Foo.bar(x, %{
        baz: "foo"
       }),~
     true <- 1 < 2 do
 # [...]
end
```

and `~` marks where's my cursor. If I then insert a new line with `RET`, this happens:

```elixir
with {:ok, _} <-
       Foo.bar(x, %{
        baz: "foo"
                   }),
    ~
     true <- 1 < 2 do
 # [...]
end
```

How could I correctly persist the indentation of a previous line?

Comment: Do you see this if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, please provide a recipe to reproduce the behavior, starting with `emacs -Q` - specify what mode you're in, etc.

Comment: Is this buffer in `elixir-mode`? If not, what is the major mode of the buffer?